# Settings entry from Settings bundle gone after update to iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, settings

So I just updated to iOS 9.3 and my settings won't show up in the Settings app.

I restarted my phone, reinstalled the app, performed a clean of the project, quit Xcode, force quit the Settings app and made sure target membership is checked on the Settings bundle, but it didn't help.

It worked fine on iOS 9.2 and below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Btw, i'm on Xcode 7.3.

Comment: I am under ios10 and I can't see any app seetings in the settings app.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. Even when reinstalling my app from the App Store, which definitively had settings shown in the settings app before, all of the settings are gone. Same seems to happen to most other apps listed in the settings app, too.
So I'm interested in a solution as well...